# Ext4: how to prevent hard links?

Tags: linux, ext4

Our backup system `duplicity` does not support Linux hard links. To prevent data loss, I want to enforce that no hard links exist on our systems. AFAIK, there is no ext4 mount option to disable hard link functionality.

I could remove the `ln` utility but this would not disable the underlying system call (and besides, I want to keep symlinks).

Anyone got a good idea how to solve this? [Recompile the kernel with EXT4_LINK_MAX set to 1?](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/6b5e09a748ad0a0b198d0e268c7e689044bfe48a/fs/ext4/ext4.h#L229)

Comment: Arguably your backups won't be incomplete because [hard linked files will be backed up](http://duplicity.nongnu.org/duplicity.1.html#sect28), multiple times even, you only can't restore them as hard links anymore but only as separate individual files.

Comment: `Anyone got a good idea how to solve this` Get a better backup system.

Comment: Trying to disable hardlinks seems like a horrible idea.  I suspect it will seriously break your system. You really should look for a better backup system.

Answer (score 0):

The first solution that comes to mind for me is creating aliases for all users so that ln = ln -s.

You can do this by creating a script in /etc/profile.d:

```
sudo vim /etc/profile.d/aliases.sh
```

Then insert your alias:

```
alias ln='ln -s'
```

Close and reopen your terminals or execute `exec bash` (assumes you're using bash)

This should prevent anyone from executing hardlinks instead of symbolic.

Comment: And when one calls `/bin/ln`, the oriignal `ln` binary is called and the alias has no effect.

Comment: Good point. In that case perhaps using a different shell? I don't know how to restrict commands in bash, not sure if you can. but lshell "limited shell" can. There's even an older SE article on doing something similar: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/91004

Could just changing the other user shells to lshell be a viable solution?

Comment: `first solution that comes to mind for me is creating aliases for all users` - The problem of course is that most programming languages other then your shell scripts will be using [link()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/link.2.html) kernel function directly, and not calling the ln binary.